# How can I update a window object in Firefox Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, developer-tools

I wanna use Chrome or Firefox Developer Tools to execute code on a website.
When I execute a "window.RR" variable lonely, it shows me the right value (it is a measure of the site's server time (in milliseconds) and every time I execute it gives me a different value). When I use it in a loop (variable c), then the variable is constant in all loops and it equals to the value of the first loop.

My code is:

```
var i;
b=window.RR;
for (i=0 ; i<400000 ; i++) {
    c=window.RR;
    if (c!==b) {
        alert(c)
    }
}
```

I expect to receive the correct value when I use it in the loop, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Is that clear what you're trying to do. Do you want to show an alert when the value of `window.RR` changes ?

Comment: @Titus
i wanna execute a code that when window.RR variable is less than a specific number, then run a function.

Comment: Instead of a loop, try to use `setInterval`, something like: `setInterval(() => { if(window.RR == 1000){alert('is 1000')}}, 100)`

Answer (score 0):

I assume the the `window.RR` variable is updated by an interval. This means that the variable is updated asynchronous.

For example, lets say that the `window.RR` holds the timestamp (in milliseconds) of the server, and the code below updates the `window.RR` every millisecond.

```
setInterval(function () {
    window.RR += 1;
}, 1);
```

If you then run a loop, that may take more than 1ms to be executed

```
var c = window.RR;
for (var i = 0; i < 999999999999999; i++){
    if (c != window.RR) { // This is always false
        console.log('This will never be printed');
    }
}
```

the `window.RR` will not change during the execution of the loop, because the javascript asynchronous codes does not run in parallel.

Thus, if the loop takes more than 1 ms to be executed `window.RR` update code will happen after the loop finish (it will have to wait any other code fired to finish before that code can be executed).

---

More info:

This code does not let any other code to run while the for loop is running.

```
var c = window.RR;
for (var i = 0; i < 999999999999999; i++){
    if (c != window.RR) { // This is always false
        console.log('This will never be printed');
    }
}
```

In order to let other code to run, you will have to make each loop async.

```
var c = window.RR;
var loop = function(i) {
    if (i < 999999999999999) {
        i++;
        if (c != window.RR) {
            console.log('This will be printed!');
        }
        else {
            // Allow other javascript codes to run
            // So that the window.RR can be updated
            setTimeout(function () {loop(i);}, 0);
        }
    }
};
loop(0);
```

Comment: thanks
but this is not the problem. running all iterations of code spend more time and in this while window.RR is constant in the loop.

Comment: Yes, but you missed my point. While the loop is running, NO other javascript code on the page run, thus the `window.RR` can not be updated. You need to make each loop asynchronous so that you give a chance to the variable update code to be executed.